# Ошибка в переводе в двоичную систему, начиная с 1 000 000 (семизначных чисел)

Tags: c, while, binary

Задача на этом участке кода : для заданного числе в десятичной системе счисления  найти то, как оно выглядит в двоичной системе счисления, затем число (binary) перевернуть и вывести. Для чисел, что меньне 1000000 это работает верно, для тех, что начинаются с 1000000 - нет. Почему? 
Я думала, что проблема в том, что int- слишком малый и пославила long long, но все равно не работает...
Буду очень благодарна за ответ, спасибо!

```
    #include <stdio.h>



int main ( int argc, char * argv []) {


   long long  remainder, base =1, bin =0, help,reverse=0, temp;
    long long number = 1000000;

    help = number;

    while (number>0){
        remainder =number %2;
        bin = bin + remainder* base;
        number /= 2;
        base *=10;

    }

    temp = bin;

    while(bin != 0){

        reverse *=  10;
        reverse += bin%10;
        bin /=10;


    }
    bin = temp;


printf(" Base 10 -  %lld, base 2 -  %lld, reverse base 2 - %lld\n", help, bin, reverse);







    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну дык логично. В строке храните, в long long тоже не влезет больше чем 2^19  при таком варианте

Comment: Что бы Вы посоветовали мне сделать?

Comment: В строке хранить. Или вообще не сохранять число, а сразу выводить.

Comment: @DontBeSoAngry, у вас есть проблемы с сохранением числа в строке? Сами справитесь?

Comment: Начать надо с того, что у вас значение в `number` хранится (после компиляции) уже в двоичной системе. Во что вы его переводите, увеличивая на каждом шаге основание системы счисления (`base`) в 10 раз, я ума не приложу. Попробуйте как-то по другому. Начните со строки (`const char *dec = "1000000";`) символов, в которой *изображено* десятичное число

Comment: @eanmos, проблемы есть (: Не думаю, что справлюсь

Comment: @eanmos, ну ладно, multithreading, но `'\0'` в конец буфера надо бы положить

Comment: @avp, спасибо :)

Comment: @DontBeSoAngry, https://ideone.com/17i76S.

Comment: С каких это пор то, что вы пытаетесь делать, называется "переводом в двоичную систему"? Вот эта вот манера: превратить десятичное число 5 в десятичное число 101 - это не имеет и никогда не имело никакого отношения к переводу в двоичную систему. Не первый раз это встречаю: откуда-то лезет эта странная манера.

Comment: @eanmos, спасибо! Попробую сейчас разобраться (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так, наверное:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( int argc, char * argv []) {


   long remainder;
   long number = 1000000;
   char buffer[65];
   char *cp;
   char b;
   int j, len;

    cp = buffer;
    while (number>0){
        remainder = number % 2;
        *cp = remainder + '0';
        number /= 2;
        cp++;
    }
    *cp = '\0';

    printf("Перевёрнутое: %s\n", buffer);

    len = strlen(buffer);
    for(j=0; j<len/2; j++) {
        b = buffer[j];
        buffer[j] = buffer[len - j -1];
        buffer[len - j -1] = b;
    }

    printf("Исходное    : %s\n", buffer);
}
```

Два момента, которые могут быть непонятными:

1. Когда в цикле мы берём остаток от деления на 2, то получаем значение **последней** двоичной цифры. Помещая его символ в **начало** строки, получаем перевёрнуту. строку. И только после перевораивания строки, получаем правильную запись.
2. Выражение *remainder + '0'* преобразует арифметическое значение переменной *remainder*  в **символ** ноля или единицы.